# Why flink can't restore from a savepoint

Tags: apache-flink, restore, checkpoint

version flink 1.7

im trying to make a flink job restore from a savepoint(or checkpoint), what the job do is reading from kafka -> do a 30-minutes-window aggregation(like a counter) -> sink to kafka.

i use rocksdb and enabled checkpoint.

now i try to trigger a savepoint manually.
the expected value of each aggregated one is 30(1 data/per minute).
but when i restore from a savepoint(flink run -d -s {url}), the aggregated value is not 30(less than 30, depends on the time i cancel flink job and restore).
when the job run normally, it gets 30.

i don't know why could some data seems to be lost?

and a log shows "No restore state for FlinkKafkaConsumer"

main code:

```
        source.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, Model>() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 5814342517597371470L;

        @Override
        public void flatMap(String value, Collector<Model> out) throws Exception {
            LOGGER.info("----> catch value: " + value);
            Model model =  JSONObject.parseObject(value, Model.class);
            out.collect(model);
        }
    }).uid("flatmap-1").name("flatmap-1").assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new AssignerWithPunctuatedWatermarks<Model>() {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -1742071229344039681L;

        @Override
        public long extractTimestamp(Model element, long previousElementTimestamp) {
            return element.getTime();
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public Watermark checkAndGetNextWatermark(Model lastElement, long extractedTimestamp) {
            return new Watermark(extractedTimestamp);
        }
    }).setParallelism(1).keyBy(Model::getDim).window(new DynamicWindowAssigner()).aggregate(new AggregateFunction<Model, Model, Model>() {
        @Override
        public Model createAccumulator() {
            return new Model();
        }

        @Override
        public Model add(Model value, Model accumulator) {
            init(value, accumulator);
            accumulator.setValue(accumulator.getValue() + 1);
            return accumulator;
        }

        @Override
        public Model getResult(Model accumulator) {
            return accumulator;
        }

        @Override
        public Model merge(Model a, Model b) {
            return null;
        }

        private void init(Model value, Model accumulator){
            if(accumulator.getTime() == 0L){
                accumulator.setValue(0);
                accumulator.setDim(value.getDim());
                accumulator.setTime(value.getTime());
            }
        }
    }).uid("agg-1").name("agg-1").map(new MapFunction<Model, String>() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -1742071229344039681L;

        @Override
        public String map(Model value) throws Exception {
            value.setTime(TimeWindow.getWindowStartWithOffset(value.getTime(), 0, TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(30)));
            return JSONObject.toJSONString(value);
        }
    }).uid("flatmap-2").name("flatmap-2").setParallelism(4).addSink(metricProducer).uid("sink").name("sink").setParallelism(2);
```

checkpoint settings:

```
    final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
    env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime);
    env.enableCheckpointing(60000);
    env.getCheckpointConfig().setCheckpointingMode(CheckpointingMode.EXACTLY_ONCE);
    env.getCheckpointConfig().setCheckpointTimeout(120000);
    env.getCheckpointConfig().setMaxConcurrentCheckpoints(1);
    env.getCheckpointConfig().setMinPauseBetweenCheckpoints(50000);
    StateBackend stateBackend = new RocksDBStateBackend(${path}, true);
    env.setStateBackend(stateBackend);
    env.getCheckpointConfig().enableExternalizedCheckpoints(CheckpointConfig.ExternalizedCheckpointCleanup.RETAIN_ON_CANCELLATION);
    env.getConfig().disableSysoutLogging();
```

Comment: "No restore state" is only logged when a checkpoint or savepoint is not being used to initialize the job's state, which explains why you are seeing incorrect results. I don't see anything obviously wrong in what you've shared, but perhaps if you share more details the problem will become apparent. (Also, are you running Flink 1.7.2, or an earlier version?)

Comment: @David Anderson thx, i use v1.7.1

Comment: @David Anderson and i checked the savepoint's hdfs dir, it seems that it contains "_meta" and other directories(which save the stream state and kafka offset?)

Comment: code was updated, and the flink cluster is combined of 3 masters, several slave nodes, flink runtime is flink-dist_2.11-1.7.1.jar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finally it turns out i should use flink run -s {savepoint} -d xxx.jar
instesad of flink run  -d xxx.jar -s {savepoint}, if "-d" flag is in front of "-s" flag , then flink ignore "-s" somehow